# How to properly load async data in vuejs with beforeRouteEnter?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am pretty new to vue.js (and vue-router) and I am trying to figure out how to load async data required to initalize some page component. According to the documentation, it can be done with `beforeRouteEnter` like this:

```
const Page = {
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      vm.foo = {
        bar: 'blah'
      };
    })
  },
  data() {
    return {
        foo: null
    };
  },
  template: '<div>{{ foo.bar }}</div>'
};
```

If I don't initialize foo properly the component render will fail with the error cause `foo.bar` is accessed before it is initialized. Ok, I can fix it by providing a default value for `foo`, but it leads me to the next questions:

1. Can vue.js possibly render any intermediate state of the component when the callback passed to next is not executed yet?
2. Is it actually the right way to load async data or should I consider some other options?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an async load then I think you're going the right way with setting a default for foo. At that point it doesn't really matter whether you're putting the load in a beforeRouteEnter or just in a created function.

As far as displaying an intermediary state what I do is just have 'pageLoading' variable that is initially true. Then I have a v-if='pageLoading' { //render spinner or whatever you want it to look like while loading } v-else { //render page normally }. This way you can have your navbars and such (whatever is outside the if/else) appear before the async load has happened so it doesn't just look like a weird blank page during the load.

Then of course you set pageLoading to false when the async load promise is fulfilled.